# Problem when comparing the date stored in the database with the date of today using momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following problem : momentJS doesn't seem to work when I try to compare dates from my database.

This is my JS code :

```
var reminderDate = new Date(item.lastReminder);

if (moment(reminderDate) < moment()) {
    console.log(moment(reminderDate).format("Y-MM-D") + ' - ' + moment().format("Y-MM-D"));
    return 'success'
} else {
    return 'danger'
}
```

This is what is displayed by the console.log :

> 2020-01-20 - 2020-01-20
>
> (4) 1970-01-1 - 2020-01-20
>
> 2020-01-20 - 2020-01-20

1970-01-1 is displayed four times because no date has been stored in the database.

However, the first line should display 2020-01-16 and 2020-01-24, not the date of today (2020-01-20)...

Thanks for your help !

Edit : The dates are stored like this in my database :

[image]

Comment: what you are getting in reminderDate, to which you are trying to apply the moment library for date format

Comment: Hi @bajran, thanks for your reply, I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `item.lastReminder` value was `2020-01-16` it would print in console:

`2020-01-16 - 2020-01-20`

You can see the result of your five inputs running the following code snippet:

```js
var inputs = ['2020-01-16', null, null, null, null, '2020-01-24'];

inputs.forEach(lastReminder => {
var reminderDate = new Date(lastReminder);

   if (moment(reminderDate).isBefore(moment())) {
       console.log(moment(reminderDate).format("Y-MM-D") + ' - ' + moment().format("Y-MM-D"));
       console.log('return success');
   } else {
       console.log('return danger');
   }
});
```

```html
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
</body>
```

And the last one would not print as it's not before today and the if condition would not be true and would return 'danger'.

The problem is in your values for `item.lastReminder`.

P.S.: Note I've changed the date comparison to use the [query function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) `isBefore`. The result is the same for this values but I prefer using query functions.